# Not able to install tensorflow for use with anaconda distribution spyder ide with bellow error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have python 3.6.5 installed and have installed Tensorflow but i am getting below error continuously please help

[error captured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbzPw.png) unable to find dll

File "", line 33, in 
    import keras

File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras__init__.py", line 3, in 
    from . import utils

File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils__init__.py", line 6, in 
    from . import conv_utils

File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in 
    from .. import backend as K

File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend__init__.py", line 89, in 
    from .tensorflow_backend import *

File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in 
    import tensorflow as tf

File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import

File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

Comment: Can you provide more information in your question such as what you were trying to do when the error happened etc...

Comment: Charlie i was working on a Artificial neural network application , for learning purpose and had to import theano, keras and tensorflow , however when a import call to keras was made the said error happened , i was working on spyder ide with python 3.6.5 version

Answer (score 0):

i search error code it because of you dont have `MSVCP140.DLL` you can try download and place it to system32 files(or you can add a path where you place it) or you can try install `Visual c++ 2015` it contains that dll

Comment: rifat i did install visual c++ 2015 redistributed but coudnt solve th eproblem

Comment: @saurabh can you find MSVCP140.DLL in your computer?

Comment: can you add C:\Windows\System32 to PYTHONPATH

Comment: @saurabh idk man if adding path wont work too go C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py edit it error causes line 343 look at maybe you can find a way

Comment: i think the problem is with the older version of CPU on my laptop and it does not support tensorflow>=1.6 versions , theres a discussion on github and a wheel file made available to resolve the issue .. will try that.. for info.. tensorflow 1.5 ran smoothly on the system yesterday